# When to use pronouns, and when to repeat yourself?

Tags: word-choice

This is a quote from one of my favorite movies:

> "There are nearly thirteen million people in the world. None of those people is an extra. They're all the leads of their own stories." - Synecdoche, New Work (2008)

Why didn't he just write:

> "There are nearly thirteen million people in the world. None of
>   **them** is an extra..."

Instead?

I have the same problem when I'm writing fiction. When to repeat yourself and when to use a pronoun?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's pretty much by ear. You have to go with what sounds good. In this case, the writer thought "people" was important enough to repeat. I happen to agree with you that "them" would have been sufficient, but sometimes the repetition works.

For example:

> government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.

Lincoln could have said

> government of, by, and for the people

or

> government of the people, by them, and for them

but the repetition makes it nearly poetry.